# Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler

Tags: java, xml

Any idea why this error is happening and how to fix it? I'm getting this error when trying to parse/load a config file:

Error

```
Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not
set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default
ErrorHandler to print the first 10 errors.  Please call
the 'setErrorHandler' method to fix this.
Error: URI=null Line=3: Document root element "persistence", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
Error: URI=null Line=3: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
null
[]
null
```

Main code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
        config = new XMLPropertiesConfiguration(new File("META-INF/vamola.xml"));                                                                                                                                   
        System.out.println(config.getString("persitence-unit.provider"));
        System.out.println(config.getList("persistence-unit.properties.name"));

    }
```

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dbBank" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>br.ufg.inf.server.Account</class>
        <class>br.ufg.inf.server.UserBank</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="derby" />
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="senha" />
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://192.168.80.125:1527/db/master/dbBank;create=true"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="OFF" />
            <property name="toplink.target-database" value="Derby" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your parsing an XML document with validation turned on, you need to specify either a DTD or an XML schema in a DOCTYPE at the start of your XML document.  Your parser is basically complaining that it doesn't know how to validate your document because no grammer has been specified to validate the mark up.

You already have an XML schema, so you probably want:

```
<!DOCTYPE schema PUBLIC "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
```

If you want to turn off validation, you need something like:

`spf.setValidating(false);`  (Where spf is a SaxParserFactory)

Comment: so how do I do set the doctype or turn off the validation?

Comment: so I need to store the dtd locally?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you can turn validation off.  You can use a URL rather than a file reference for the DTD if you want to use one.

Comment: Actually, when I looked at your XML again, you already have a scaema referenced so you can probably set the doctype to use that (see above).

Comment: DTD is a bit obselete. Furthermore, jpa uses XSD

Comment: but where do I put this dtd, in the xml file?

Comment: No just use <!DOCTYPE schema PUBLIC "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
I think that should do it.

Comment: (Get that from the answer it's self, it all went a bit wrong when I copied it into the comment)

Comment: You might want to read a bit about doctype declarations before giving advice: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-doctypedecl ... your "DOCTYPE schema" doesn't say "use this schema", it says "expect a root element named 'schema' and use this referenced doctype"

Comment: When I try this adding: <!DOCTYPE schema PUBLIC "java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">, I just get another exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

Answer (score 4):

The exception says that an `ErrorHandler` wasn't set. This means that the parser uses its built-in error handler, which simply writes messages to the console. If you actually want to validate, you need to create an [ErrorHandler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) implementation and attach it to the `DocumentBuilder`.

For more information, read this: http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=xml.parsing (error handlers are about 1/3 of the way down).

Or, as other responses have suggested, you can just turn validation off.

Answer (score 0):

The XML document defines the default namespace `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence` and includes a url, where the schema can be found (`xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, first value is the namespace, second the url or path).

Please double-check if this url is accessible at the time you parse it. An alternative is to download the schema, put it on the file system and modify the `xsi:schemaLocation` value.