# Turn off org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler Validation-Warning in BaseX

Tags: java, basex

I get the following warnings reading/writing XML files with baseX:

> Warnung: Validierung wurde eingeschaltet, aber es wurde kein org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler festgelegt. Dies ist wahrscheinlich nicht beabsichtigt. Parser druckt die ersten 0 Fehler mit einem Standard-ErrorHandler. Rufen Sie die Methode "setErrorHandler" auf, um dies zu beheben.
>   Error: URI=null Line=1: Document Root-Element "dataset"muss mit DOCTYPE-Root "null" übereinstimmen.
>   Error: URI=null Line=1: Dokument ist ungültig. Keine Grammatik gefunden.

Sorry for german. maybe it is clear without translation.

However I have to read/write a lot of times. So if each io-process produces this 3 lines of console-output it will probably overwrite things like important error-messages.
How can i turn this warnings off or how can i turn document-validation off?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866886/warning-validation-was-turned-on-but-an-org-xml-sax-errorhandler) is related. Seems that one have to overwrite the sax-parser.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to reproduce the issue, and probably should better go for the BaseX mailing list. This feels like a corrupted database (try running `OPTIMIZE ALL` after taking a backup copy) or BaseX bug (try using the newest release).

Comment: It occurs when reading a .xml file without a valid xml-header.. Now you can argue that any xml-file should have a valid xml-header.. But there are many xml-like dataformats that don't have one.. imo one should be able to easily turn off validation. But yes, discussing that is misplaced here..

Comment: This does not seem like an expected message, and BaseX allows any well-formed XML (it must not be valid, and actually BaseX does not even directly support DTD or schema validation). If you can put together a small example on the BaseX mailing list, you'll either get an explanation what's going on and why, or any issue will likely be fixed shortly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866886/warning-validation-was-turned-on-but-an-org-xml-sax-errorhandler)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the **setValidating(false)** for the DocumentBuilderFactory instance using in the application.
see the example below;

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = docBuilder.parse(samlinResponse);
```